# Is there an illness caused by the Force?

Tags: star-wars

Not including a person becoming a practitioner of the dark side of the Force, are there any Force related illnesses? Any malady caused by the Force itself?

Is there any reason that there couldn't be a Force related illness?

Comment: I am not that deeply into the Star Wars universe, so I'm not too sure what's considered canon/non-canon these days, but there is something called [force psychosis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_psychosis).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you include mental illness, then absolutely yes. [Force Psychosis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_psychosis) appears in a considerable number of Star Wars novels including [Millennium Falcon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon_(novel)).

There's also a [Force Headache](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_headache) (which appears in the comic series [Knight Errant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knight_Errant))

[image]

and the [Dark Plague](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Plague) (which appears in SWTOR)

[image]

Comment: Also related to Force psychosis were Fallanassi illusions that could make people physically ill

Comment: I'm getting Force Headache just from the ridiculous amount of idiocy injected into C-canon by some later works.

Comment: Now I'm curious what that one solution is...

Comment: @flq - Killing people; http://i.stack.imgur.com/AyGfr.jpg

Comment: @flq Sounds like clickbait: "Find out how a young force sensitive beat Force Headaches with one weird trick."

Comment: @Liesmith - Jedi hate him, find out why...